# Delaying rising edge of input signal - 3.3v logic

Tags: signal, delay, edge

I'm new here and I need help with my project. I working on my DIY home automation and I need to delay rising edge of the input signal. Trigger is faling edge. I need to delay it 100 - 500ms and I use 3.3V logic. Any idea how to do it? Circuit example would be welcome. Thanks a lot for any tip/proposal. More details of the purpose for such delayed signal:
The source of the signal is RESET from Wemos D1 Mini generated by micro switch or CH340C and load/target is OE pin of TXS0108 - logic level shifter. I need to delay enabling of TXS010E, OE pin, otherwise Wemos didn't start/boot. So I need some kind of circuit/IC which will do it.
 [image]

Comment: You need a monostable

Comment: Is it resettable ? What is shortest input pulse? Is it retriggerable during delay?  i,e, triggered after 1st pulse or last pulse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Daniel, you need to learn about the 74HC221 Dual Monostable Multi-Vibrator IC. Download the data sheet from Digikey and study it.

It is pretty simple to apply. Connect your low-going 3.3v logic signal to the "A" input. When this input experiences the low-going edge of your signal it will produce an output on "Q" & "Q-bar". "Q" is a high-going pulse and "Q-bar" is a low-going pulse. They are identical in duration and virtually simultaneous. You will use the Q-bar output for your application and ignore the Q output (simply don't connect it to anything).

The duration of the output pulse is determined by a resistor and capacitor you connect to the appropriate pins of the IC. The data sheet will explain this and how to calculate the required values of the R & C. Basically, the larger the R and C values,  the longer the output pulse. As a starting place I'd assume a 0.1 MFD ceramic cap and calculate the required resistor value for the delay you want.

There are a few other inputs to each section of this chip. Follow the data sheet and tie them to appropriate "logic levels" : i.e. Gnd or 3.3 volts. Make sure you tie the CLR-bar input high. Also tie the "B" input high (3.3. volts).

If you are not using the other section of the IC, make sure to connect all inputs to either GND  or 3.3. Leave the outputs unconnected as well as the R & C pins. Failure to do this will likely result in erratic operation of the other section.

The 74xx221 is a good IC to get to know well. It will come in handy for many situations. It is produced in several of the 74xx logic families. Make sure you choose the "HC" (not "HCT") or another family which will operate on 3.3. volts. Some families need a minimum of 4.5 volts supply to operate properly.

Also, make sure you connect a bypass capacitor between its supply pins ( 8 & 16) as close to the pins as you can get it. Use two caps - a 0.1 or 0.01 MFD ceramic in parallel with a tantalum of 1.0 to 3.3 MFD. These values are not critical. What's critical is that you have these caps connected. Without them you will likely experience erratic operation.

Most importantly, read the data sheet carefully and study the timing diagrams and truth table to understand what operation you can expect from this device.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing the details of what the driving signal is and what the load is I offer the following:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6Q63u.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A simple RC time delay with fast discharge.*

How it works:

- When IN goes high C1 charges up exponentially via R1. This sets your time delay which can be calculated from \$ \tau = RC \$ (seconds) approximately. For 500 ms you could try 1 μF and 470 kΩ.
- When IN goes low C1 is rapidly discharged by D1 and OUT goes low.

Comment: The simple RC time delay I can't use. The source of the signal is RESET from Wemos D1 Mini and load is OE of TXS0108. I need to delay anabling of TXS010E otherwise Wemos didn't start/boot. So I need some kind of circuit/IC which will do it. I put this information into the main topic.

Comment: That should have been stated in the question along with links to the datasheets for each. Why do you think this won't work with the OE?

Comment: I'm not sure whether discharging capacitor via CH340C reset output pin will not fry it. I'm a bit afraid of doing it this way. And discharge needs to be fast, otherwise I wouldn't be able to upload new scatch/code into Wemos.

Answer (score 1):

You can provide delay by using 555timer IC.

I used this in one of my project to provide delay for sequencing.

Comment: To make this a better answer, could you show how to create the delay with a 555?

Comment: http://electronicsmaker.com/em/admin/pdfs/free/Time.pdf

please consider this link. it will help you in designing delay using 555 timer ic

Comment: @ROHIT - Welcome :-) (a) As a new user, please read the [tour] and [help] to learn more about the site. (b) Answers should be self-contained. Links can "die" and so there must be enough detail in the answer, for it to be complete. Links should only give *supplementary* information. Links in comments are even less valid as part of a answer, since comments can be deleted at any time. (c) In the question, 3.3V logic is mentioned, so it is reasonable to expect there to be a 3.3V supply rail. Please check the minimum supply voltage for a normal 555 timer in that link. Do you see the problem?

Comment: ok I got it I will share the exact circuit